# http://localhostにアクセスするとphpファイルがダウンロードされる

Tags: php, macos, apache, nginx

タイトルの通りです。
ページが開かず以下のテキストだけダウンロードされます。

```
<html>

<body>
  <h1>It works!</h1>
  <?=   "この列を表示" ?>
</body>


</html>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

MacOS High-Sierra 10.13.6
mac標準のapacheは
`sudo apachectl stop`し、
homebrewから入れたnginx, httpdはそれぞれ
`brew services stop`したのですが、
そもそもなぜlocalhostにアクセスできている？のかわかりません。

Comment: webサーバとしては`httpd`(Apache)と`nginx`のどちらを使用するつもりでしょうか？機能が被るので同時に使用する必要は無いはずです。

Comment: @cubick とりあえずnginxを使いたいです。そして、再起動したらnginxのindex.htmlにはアクセスできました...